# How to show all results and not just one in a delegate calculator

Tags: c#, wpf, delegates, calculator

I just got the task to create a WPF application that shows the results for different calculations (+,-,/,%,etc.) by using a delegate (public delegate 
void Calculation(int a, int b). 
The problem is that my program only seems to show the last result of those calculations but I need to show them all in a listbox.

This is my code right now:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
      public delegate string CalculateHandler(int a, int b);
      public MainWindow()
      {
           InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void BtnCalculate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { 

        CalculateHandler Calculate = new CalculateHandler(Add.Addition);
        Calculate += Subtract.Subtraction;
        Calculate += Multi.Multiplication;
        Calculate += Div.Division;
        Calculate += Root.Ro;
        Calculate += Mod.Modulo;
        Calculate += Pot.Potency;

        int a = Int32.Parse(TextBoxZahlA.Text); 
        int b = Int32.Parse(TextBoxZahlB.Text);

        listBox.Items.Add(Calculate(a, b));
        listBox.Items.Refresh(); 
    }
}
```

Example for one of the calculations:

```
class Multi
{
    public static string Multiplication (int a, int b)
        {
            string result3 = a + " * " + b + " = " + (a * b);
            return result3;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any sort of help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a good approach would be to create a list that holds the handlers for each calculation. Then use a for-each loop and calculate the values and add them to the listBox.

**Like this:**

```
            List<CalculateHandler> CalculateHandlers = new List<CalculateHandler>();
            CalculateHandlers.Add(Add.Addition);
            CalculateHandlers.Add(Subtract.Subtraction);
            CalculateHandlers.Add(Multi.Multiplication);
            ....

            int a = Int32.Parse(textBox.Text);
            int b = Int32.Parse(textBox_Copy.Text);

            foreach (var handler in CalculateHandlers)
            {
                listBox.Items.Add(handler(a, b));
            }

            listBox.Items.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `Calculate(a, b)`, it will run all the delegates, but only the last one will be returned as the return value. One solution would be to use an array of delegates and iterate over that, or to have each delegate add to the `listBox.Items` (though I wouldn't recommend that, as it's duplicated effort).